# Order of execution of the document.getReady()

Tags: jquery

We are rendering our html based on various components on a page.

If all the compoents have document.ready() function in them, here are my questions

1. Will all the components be rendered parallel or one after
   another?
2. What is the best approach to render all these components with a
   good user experience?
3. Any good example websites if you know of implementing the
   technique?

Thank you
D

Comment: The `ready` handlers will run sequentially. (Handlers cannot run in parallel because Javascript code embedded in web pages is executed on a single thread.)

Comment: Which means that for some reason if a document.ready() is stuck trying to load some data, the rest of the page will not load? Right?

Comment: @AlexAdams: no. if loading is an asynchronous process javascript is still being executed on the client side while requests are pending server response.

Answer (score 0):

### Answers

1. **Javascript is a single-threaded process** (unless using web workers which don't interact with the UI) so components always execute (even if that manipulates their UI display) serially.

   > **Note:** Any remote loading using asynchronous technique (Ajax requests are by default async) doesn't block javascript execution engine which can (and usually does) execute other queued code).
2. All components that are more or less static should be pre-prepared on the server. The same goes for those that change after a longer time into page lifetime.
3. Sencha's ExtJS framework is a great example of a completely client-side built UI that proves this can be done. And with today's browsers' speed it shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Comment: Thank you Robert. Good answer. Thanks for your time in answering the same.

Comment: @AlexAdams: If you find my answer helpful, you can always accept it a such.